# how to decode characters in utf - 8 format in android

Tags: android

i have the following text in my strings.xml file

\n\nSVG Service Verlags GmbH & Co. KG \n
        Schwertfegerstra?e 1-3\n
        D-23556 L?beck\n

this is german text.
i need to decode this using utf-8 and then set it as text of a textview.
how do i go about this

thank you in advance.

EDIT:

i have tried the following

String decodedstring = URLDecoder.decode(nodevalue, "UTF-8");

this also does not work. why does this not work?

Answer (score 3):

Some things to check.

1. Make sure your xml is tagged with the right encoding.
2. Make sure your xml file is SAVED with the right encoding.  Looking at the text you pasted (from a browser?) it looks like the file is already mangled.  Schwertfegerstra?e should be Schwertfegerstraße.

When you open the file you need to use an InputStreamReader with the encoding set.

See this page for an example:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-utf-8-encoded-data-from-a-file-java/

The key bit is:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
```

Comment: i have the text coming via a string and not a file.

Comment: Oh - sorry.  I thought you were reading an xml file.  If it is in your strings.xml file, then all you need to do to use as the text of a TextView is in your view definition do something like android:text="@string/text_name" where text_name is the id you gave it in your strings.xml file.